# Polymer: how to inline external scripts

Tags: polymer

I am trying to figure out if it is possible to inline external javascripts in my Polymer elements. I know if I have a link to a stylesheet then it gets merged (from http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/styling.html):

```
<polymer-element name="my-element">
  <template>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="my-element.css">
     ...
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer('my-element',...);
  </script>
</polymer>
```

Polymer will automatically inline the my-element.css stylesheet using a :

```
<polymer-element ...>
  <template>
    <style>.../* Styles from my-element.css */...</style>
     ...
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer('my-element',...);
  </script>
</polymer>
```

I am looking for a way to do the same with external javascript files:

```
<polymer-element name="my-element">
  <template>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="my-element.css">
     ...
  </template>
  <script src="my-element.js">
</polymer>
```

and get something like this:

```
<polymer-element ...>
  <template>
    <style>.../* Styles from my-element.css */...</style>
     ...
  </template>
  <script>.../* code from my-element.js */...</script>
</polymer>
```

I looked at `vulcanize` (https://github.com/Polymer/vulcanize) but it does not seem to be able to do it.

EDIT:

let me rephrase what I want to achieve:

I know that when vulcan processes a HTML page that contains elements, it merges the templates of these elements into the resulting output, and (given the `--csp` option) it also creates a javascript file where it puts all embedded scripts of the elements. I want to be able to merge into the resulting `.js` file not only embedded scripts but also scripts that are linked to from my elements.

Answer (score 1):

It should work as you wrote it, except that `<script>` requires a closing tag. I.e.

```
<polymer-element name="my-element">
  <template>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="my-element.css">
     ...
  </template>
  <script src="my-element.js"></script>
</polymer>
```

Fwiw, the script in either case is loaded and executed normally by the browser. In that sense, it's different from the `stylesheet` link which is a feature being simulated by Polymer.

For the same reason, you can load/run that script anywhere. The tag doesn't have to be inside the `<polymer-element>`.

Comment: thank you, it works like this, yes, I just would like to not have an external file but have it inline. I just need an external file for development so that my editor knows how to auto-indent etc, but when I build I want to have this script inside my polymer element inline. Is this possible?

Comment: Sorry yes, I misunderstood, it's clearer now. I don't know off hand if vulcanizer has this ability, have you tried the --inline option?

Comment: Fwiw, if it's your *editor* that's causing this problem, consider finding one that supports editing embedded JavaScript. :)